# Need guidance in delimiter for regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, rsyslog

Trying to send multiline Kafka log from RSYSLOG to FLuentd.

```
(?<date>\[.*?\]) (.*?) ((.|\n*)*)
```

Here is the link:
https://regex101.com/r/iFHyTi/1

But my regex is considering next timestamp pattern as a single line. Requirement is to stop before the next timestamp starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match all subsequent lines that start with either a TAB or a space char:

```
(?<date>\[[^][]*]) ([A-Z]+) (.*(?:\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xae1bi/2).

*Details*

- `(?<date>\[[^][]*])` - Group "date": `[`, zero or more chars other than square brackets, `]`
- - space
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 2: one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- - space
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*)*)` - Group 3:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other that line break chars as many as possible
  - `(?:\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*)*` - zero or more sequences of

    - `\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)` - a newline, LF, char not followed with `[`, four digis, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits
    - `.*` - any zero or more chars other that line break chars as many as possible

Comment: [link] (https://regex101.com/r/xae1bi/1) If I just reverse the order of ERROR and INFO it doesn't work. Say, I have 3 blocks (error, info and error) then the regex won't work. Can you help on that regex?

Comment: @gomzi007 Ok, what about excluding `[` at the start of a line? `(?<date>\[.*?\]) (.*?) (.*(\n[^[\r\n].*)*)`?

Comment: @gomzi007 See also `(?<date>\[[^][]*]) ([A-Z]+) (.*(?:\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*)*)`

Comment: -(?<date>\[[^][]*]) ([A-Z]+) (.*(?:\n(?!\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*)*) This looks perfect since the other regex was breaking into one extra group. Bow to you..